# VS2012 DBML Changing Connection String

Tags: linq, visual-studio, connection-string, dbml

I have a solution which contains multiple projects, such as a class library, websites, services, etc.

Projects such as the class library and service have a dbml connection to the same database. This means that the projects have connection strings such as:

```
MySolution.ClassLibrary.DatabaseA
MySolution.ClassLibrary.DatabaseB
MySolution.ClassLibrary.DatabaseC
MySolution.Service.DatabaseA
MySolution.Service.DatabaseD
```

This is a bit messy as I'm duplicating the connection strings. For integration purposes, I've also added another class library of shared components - which also has access to the same databases (Different tables). So I now have 3 instances of the same connection string in some places!

As mentioned, this is not only messy, but also leaves it open to bugs because if a connection string is missing from a website or service it will end up attempting to point at our development database (because it is defaulting to the setting from the class library).

What I would really like is simply to have a non or generically namespaced version of the connection string and just share it everywhere, e.g.

```
MySolution.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseA
MySolution.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseB
MySolution.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseC
MySolution.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseD
```

Then I would point each dbml at these connection strings and job done!

The problem is that VS2012 is so buggy when changing connection strings in the (right click > properties of the) dbml. It confuses itself between app or web.configs and Settings.settings - often when selecting DatabaseConnectingStringA, it will create a new one called DatabaseConnectionStringA1, which is very frustrating! It will also always add it's own namespace to connection strings when you add it through the project settings - which is required for the dbml.

Has anyone got a trick or method to get VS to do this?

Comment: In the end, only the connection string from the running assembly matters. The others are only stored to know which database you used to generate the model. So you only have to make sure that the running assemblies themselves don't contain DBML's.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did find a solution. It's not perfect, but it has reduced my connection strings from 7 or 8 (in certain places) down to 4 which I can copy and paste in between all projects for the various debug/release/staging builds.

Basically, for each DBML I added a partial class with a constructor which specifically uses my connection string:

```
partial class MyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext() : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master.DatabaseA"].ConnectionString)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Then, after loading the DBML file where I could see all of the tables, I right clicked and chose properties in the background and changed the connection to None.

This has meant that the Web or App Config will look for a connection string of just "Master.DatabaseA" without referencing the project namespaces.

I then also cleared out the old connection strings in the other projects and it all works cleanly now. The only issue is that I need to set the connection back to None each time a new table or stored procedure is added. The project will not build in this situation so it can't accidentally be missed.